# GET a website url when routing

Tags: node.js, express

Sorry, my vocabulary is very limited, any help clarifying this question is deeply appreciated.

I'm building a server using Nodejs and Express, it has a route like `/new/:url`. I access the value passed on the url by using `req.params.url`. This works well for simple strings, like `chocolate`, however, if I pass a website url, like `http://www.google.com`, then it won't be routed to `/new/:url`.

**Question:** how can I pass a website url and access it with Node/Express?

**Edit:** I am trying to use the GET method, and apparently a way to solve this problem is through Wildcards/Regex.

Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: Use encodeURIComponent, but be careful when doing such [an open redirect](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was Regex. Instead of routing as `/new/:url`, I used:

```
/new/:url(*)
```

So that if `http://www.google.com` is given as a parameter:

```
req.params.url = "http://www.google.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Post method.

1. Set header "Content-Type" : "application/json"
2. Set body { "urlblahblah~" : "https://www.google.com" }
3. Then parse It as JSON in server-side

Answer (score 1):

you can use Javascripts encodeURIComponent, so when you passing to your server on client, you will allsways encode the url, so you can pass it as regular parameter. or as mentioned by Hulk if posting is an options you can pass it as body param as well...

```
var url = encodeURIComponent("http://some.url/asdasa?asdas=12312")
```

will result in :

```
"http%3A%2F%2Fsome.url%2Fasdasa%3Fasdas%3D12312"
```

which is safe for passing as param